# ViewPager внутри ViewPager - такие матрешки работают?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Доброго времени суток. Назрела новая задача.
Есть каталог мастеров. При выборе конкретного мастера открывается его страница (активити с ViewPager), и теперь мастеров можно перелистывать свайпом. Это все работает. При попытке добавить на страницу мастера SlidingTabLayout началась странная штука с перелистыванием и отображением информации:
1) Бегунок индикатора останавливается где-то между табами;
2) Отображается не выбранный мастер, при перелистывании видно, что выбираемого мастера нет в списке мастеров вообще.
Сомневаюсь, что кому то сейчас интересно смотреть исходники того, что слепили, хочется немного теории. Сталкивался кто-нибудь со SlidingTabLayout внутри ViewPagera и, если да, поделитесь, пожалуйста, опытом.